# Переключение значения аргумента addMouseListener и addMouseMotionListener по кнопке

Tags: java

На форме есть 2 взаимовыключающих *togglebtn* (нажимая одну я активирую режим "карандаш", нажимая вторую я активирую режим "линия"). Для рисования произвольных изображения я создал класс *PaintPanel* наследник от *JPanel*, и поместил в него 2 класса: *MyMouseHandler* (рисует карандашом) и *DrawLine* (рисует линии) наследники от MouseAdapter. В переопределенном методе *setBackground* класса *PaintPanel* создаю экземпляры вышеперечисленных 2х классов рисования и через условия пытаюсь выбирать соответствующий аргумент по нажатию соответствующей кнопки... **Не работает**...

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void setBackground(Color bg) {
        super.setBackground(BACK_COLOR);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT));

        handler = new MyMouseHandler();
        lineHandler = new DrawLine();

        if (penToggleBtn.isSelected()) {
        this.addMouseListener(handler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        }

        if (lineToggleBtn.isSelected()) {   
        this.addMouseListener(lineHandler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(lineHandler);
        }
    }
```

Если комментирую одно из условия, и с оставшегося убираю *if*, то работает. Подскажите как реализовать эту задумку?

Пример кода с *addItemListener*

```
penToggleBtn = new JToggleButton("P");
    penToggleBtn.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            brushPanel.addMouseListener(handler);
            brushPanel.addMouseMotionListener(handler);

        }
    });
    lineToggleBtn = new JToggleButton("Line");
    lineToggleBtn.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            brushPanel.addMouseListener(lineHandler);

        }
    });
```

Comment: А Вы с помощью отладчика посмотрите, что происходит в данном методе.

Comment: Предположу, что в момент, когда вызывается `setBackground` обе кнопки не выбраны. Вообще, почему именно в `setBackground`, а не в каком-нибудь `penToggleButton.addItemListener`?

Comment: @zRrr, я так тоже пробовал. При запуске приложения, кнопочка *penToggleButton* у меня уже по умолчанию нажата, т.е. активирован режим рисования карандашом. Далее я переключаюсь на кнопку "линия", и вроде все нормально, активируется другой режим рисования, но он работает не так как должен(рисует и линию и произвольно и как угодно в общем + вывод координа в консоль), и если я возвращаюсь в "карандаш", то рисования становится карандашным, но режим печати координат в консоль от кнопки "линия" не отключается, и на последней точне произвольных линий остается пиксель цвета из режима "линия"...

Comment: пример добавил выше